# Microsoft LUIS doesn't recognize an Entity

Tags: nlp, azure-language-understanding

I've created model for MS LUIS.
It recognizes intents sharply, but no any entity recognized or recognized partly.
What can be wrong?

My steps are: 
import new version in LUIS app -> Train -> Publish -> Test.

When I type utterance from model example - it finds.

Also e.g. when I type: "create task check why it doesn't show all", I am getting this (small part of taskName):

```
 "entities": [
{
  "entity": "check why",
  "type": "taskName",
  "startIndex": 12,
  "endIndex": 20,
  "score": 0.8236943,
  "role": ""
}
]
```

here is  JSON model:

```
{
 "luis_schema_version": "3.0.0",
 "versionId": "0.12",
 "name": "Todo-Agent 0.4",
 "desc": "This LUIS app has a  AddTask and None intents.",
 "culture": "en-us",
 "intents": [
{
  "name": "AddTask"
},
],
 "entities": [
{
  "name": "taskName",
  "roles": []
}
 ],
 "composites": [],
 "closedLists": [],
 "patternAnyEntities": [],
 "regex_entities": [],
 "prebuiltEntities": [],
 "model_features": [],
 "regex_features": [],
 "patterns": [
   {
  "pattern": "add task - {taskName}",
  "intent": "AddTask"
},
{
  "pattern": "create task {taskName}",
  "intent": "AddTask"
}
 ],
 "utterances": [
{
  "text": "2",
  "intent": "None",
  "entities": []
},
{
  "text": "5",
  "intent": "None",
  "entities": []
},
{
  "text": "add the task - do something",
  "intent": "AddTask",
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "taskName",
      "startPos": 15,
      "endPos": 26
    }
  ]
},
{
  "text": "add the task test text",
  "intent": "AddTask",
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "taskName",
      "startPos": 13,
      "endPos": 21
    }
  ]
},
{
  "text": "bla bla",
  "intent": "None",
  "entities": []
},
{
  "text": "create task bad response",
  "intent": "AddTask",
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "taskName",
      "startPos": 12,
      "endPos": 23
    }
  ]
},
{
  "text": "create task check again",
  "intent": "AddTask",
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "taskName",
      "startPos": 12,
      "endPos": 22
    }
  ]
},
{
  "text": "create task check entity",
  "intent": "AddTask",
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "taskName",
      "startPos": 12,
      "endPos": 23
    }
  ]
},
{
  "text": "create task do something wrong",
  "intent": "AddTask",
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "taskName",
      "startPos": 12,
      "endPos": 29
    }
  ]
},
{
  "text": "create task go home",
  "intent": "AddTask",
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "taskName",
      "startPos": 11,
      "endPos": 18
    }
  ]
},
{
  "text": "create task testone",
  "intent": "AddTask",
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "taskName",
      "startPos": 12,
      "endPos": 18
    }
  ]
}
 ]
}
```

Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've solved the issue by including some very different utterances with different 'taskName' values and it's length (specially length!! - it stoped to cut taskName).

e.g.

```
  {
  "text": "create item test with my personal bot and see what will happen when i type some long task name and than can train and publish model when it works great",
  "intent": "AddTask",
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "taskName",
      "startPos": 12,
      "endPos": 142
    }
  ]
},
```